# Can a putty terminal window be made viewable in a web browser?

Tags: ssh, browser, putty

I often remotely connect via putty to client computers over ssh.

I would like to share my putty session so the client can see the commands I'm running from a web browser.

Is this possible to do?

Note I know it's possible to share a window using the Linux screen command.

Comment: yes its possible... there is a package in Mint's software repo that does this.  If I come across it, ill post it.

Comment: Can we assume that you are connecting from a windows machine to a Linux server? And that you have root access to the Linux machine? Is there a webserver running on the client Linux machines?

Comment: Yes I'm connecting to Linux from Windows via putty. Yes I have root. And yes a webserver is running.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do this is saving the terminal session into a file and then accessing that file with a browser. Since your question gives very little information about your setup, I will assume that i) you are connecting to *nix clients, ii) the client can serve a webpage.

The main tool here is a program called `script` :

```
 script makes a typescript of everything printed on your termi‐
 nal.  It is useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an
 interactive session as proof of an assignment, as the typescript
 file can be printed out later with lpr(1).
```

You can install on Debian based distros using

```
sudo apt-get install script
```

Then create a simple HTML file on the remote machine with the following contents and save it as `output.htm` (**make sure it is accessible from the internet**):

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2"> 
</head>

<body>
<pre>
```

The `<meta>` tag makes the page refresh every 2 seconds and the `<pre>` tag ensures  that new lines and spaces are displayed correctly.

Now, once you log on to the remote machine run `script -af output.htm`. That will append (`-a`) a transcript of your terminal session to the file `output.htm`. Your client can then access `http://remote.server.com/output.txt` and watch the commands as they appear.

CAVEATS:

If you use colored output in your terminal, the [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) that make the colors will be visible in your html output.

Comment: Thank you terdon. I was hoping to be able to show terminal window activity in real time inside the browser. But this may be an alternative.

Comment: Here comes your overdue first upvote. Time and time again I'm surprised how answers into which an author puts a lot of effort go unnoticed and unvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to checkout shellinabox. Here's a good tutorial. Enjoy!

http://www.tecmint.com/shell-in-a-box-a-web-based-ssh-terminal-to-access-remote-linux-servers/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.